# SFTP issue, getting Failed initialization randomly

Tags: curl, sftp

I am getting Failed initialization error during SFTP, facing this issue very randomly, most of the time SFTP is successful.Dont know what are the possible reasons for this.

Please assist.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OSX or Linux...
open a terminal and connect to your SFTP server using SSH2 protocol.

```
$ ssh [username]@[server hostname]
```

example,

```
$ ssh theRemix@mysftpserver.com
```

Check if there are any errors that are reported.

If you are on windows...
use a tool such as Putty to connect to your SFTP server using SSH2 protocol.
Check if there are any errors that are reported.

Comment: i am using linux, ssh is working, and as i said most of the time issue is not der but very randomly getting SFTP issue. What else can be the reason